# Error Received while importing data using Flat File into SQL server

Tags: sql-server, import, etl, oledb

I am trying to import a flat file into SQL Server table and I received an error below. I verified the mappings looks good and around 5million data gets loaded into the table and then it fails. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

- Copying to [dbo].[TABLE1] (Error)

Messages

```
Error 0xc0202009: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Communication link failure".
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "TCP Provider: The semaphore timeout period has expired.
".
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
 
Error 0xc0209029: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Destination - TABLE1.Inputs[Destination Input]" failed because error code 0xC020907B occurred, and the error row disposition on "Destination - TABLE1.Inputs[Destination Input]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
 
Error 0xc0047022: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Destination - TABLE1" (370) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "Destination Input" (383). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
 
Error 0xc02020c4: Data Flow Task 1: The attempt to add a row to the Data Flow task buffer failed with error code 0xC0047020.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
 
Error 0xc0047038: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on Source - TABLE1_txt returned error code 0xC02020C4.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
```

Answer (score 0):

`TCP Provider: The semaphore timeout period has expired`
Try to use [Chunks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/appendchunk-method-ado?view=sql-server-ver15)  and take a look here for [Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/appendchunk-and-getchunk-methods-example-vb?view=sql-server-ver15).
Please also specify how big `FlatFile` (the bigger one) you are trying to put into SQL Server ?